# Ajax executing different form on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, flask

I've created two forms and assigned different submit button IDs. But ajax is executing single form every time even if I execute different button for different ajax call. Following is the code:

Form1.

```
<button class='btn genz-light-red'type='submit'
                style="margin-top:20px;width:50%; background:#FF1744; height:33px;color:white;" id="customButton">Enroll</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
        key: 'pk_test_YgHVTCLIMQLW4NV6ntnJPAXs',
        image: '/assets/img/icons/GenZ_Logo.png',
        locale: 'auto',
        token: function (token) {

                        $("#stripeToken").val(token.id);
                        $("#stripeEmail").val(token.email);
                        $("#monthlyForm").submit();
                        $.ajax({
                            url: '/monthlycharged',
                            data: $('form').serialize(),
                            type: 'POST',
                            success: function(response) {
                                console.log(response);
                            },
                            error: function(error) {
                                console.log(error);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });

                $('#customButton').on('click', function (e) {

                    handler.open({
                        name:'Monthly',
                        description:'Monthly Package',
                        amount:1450
                    });
                    e.preventDefault();
                });

                $(window).on('popstate', function () {
                    handler.close();
                });

                </script>
```

Form2:

```
<form action='/cancelannual' method='post'><a href="/cancelannual">
                        <input class='btn genz-light-red'style=";width:50%; background:#FF1744; height:33px;color:white;"type="submit" value="Cancel" /></a></form>
            <!-- Custom Button -->
                <form id="yearlyForm" action="/yearlycharged" method="post" >

                    <div class="form-group">
                <input type="hidden" id="stripeToken" name="stripeToken" />
                <input type="hidden" id="stripeEmail" name="stripeEmail" />
                <button class='btn genz-light-red'type='submit'
                style="margin-top:20px;width:50%; background:#FF1744; height:33px;color:white;" id="customButton1">Enroll</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
                    key: 'pk_test_YgHVTCLIMQLW4NV6ntnJPAXs',
                    image: '/assets/img/icons/GenZ_Logo.png',
                    locale: 'auto',
                    token: function (token) {

                        $("#stripeToken").val(token.id);
                        $("#stripeEmail").val(token.email);
                        $("#yearlyForm").submit();
                        $.ajax({
                            url: '/yearlycharged',
                            data: $('form').serialize(),
                            type: 'POST',
                            success: function(response) {
                                console.log(response);
                            },
                            error: function(error) {
                                console.log(error);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });

                $('#customButton1').on('click', function (e) {
                    handler.open({
                        name:'Yearly',
                        description:'Yearly Package',
                        amount:9500
                    });
                    e.preventDefault();
                });

                // Close Checkout on page navigation
                $(window).on('popstate', function () {
                    handler.close();
                });

                </script>
```

If I click on "customButton" it processes yearly subscription if I click on "customButton1" still it processes yearly subscription instead of monthly. Surprisingly when form popups it has the monthly values in it. But after processing database shows Yearly package processed. In my python/flask code without ajax I can process both packages seperately so the problem is not in my views it lies somewhere in Ajax. Please advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two `var handler` declarations in the global scope - the second hides the first. Name them differently or wrap both code fragments in separate `$(document).ready(function() {...});`

Comment: There is a problem. It worked when I changed "var handler" to "var handlera" and 'handler.open" to "handlera.open" for yearly package. Now yearly package worked fine but as soon as I tested monthly it also worked fine. When I came back to yearly it is not sending data to stripe at all with no error. Can you suggest the correct way?

Comment: @AnonymousCoder - you have duplicate element id-s in different forms on the same page ("stripeToken", "stripeEmail"). This is incorrect and selectors such as `$("#stripeToken")` do not return the jQuery object for elements that you expect.

Comment: What is the correct way? Because stripeToken and stripeEmail are both share same values across all forms. Apologies if I am not good at it but I just need to make sense out of it.

Comment: The correct way is not to have multiple DOM elements with the same value of `id` attribute.